# Odd characters in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I have been recently working on a website that takes input from the arduino ie- temperature and humidity. But there is a fatal problem that I've encountered, the serial monitor spews out some garbage with some actual readings. Is there a way to eliminate this?

```
 ╰─λ cat /dev/ttyACM0
T0°C
Humidity: 39.00%
00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
Temperature: 32.70°C
Humidity: 39.00%
idit9.00Tempure:70°Humi: 39
emperatu32.7
Huty: 0%
idit9.00Tempure:70°umidity.00%Tratu32.7
idit9.00Tempture.70�Humi: 39
empere: 0°Cmidi39.0
atur°C
Hum9.00
```

code-

```
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>

#define DHTPIN 4

#define DHTTYPE    DHT11
DHT_Unified dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

uint32_t delayMS;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  sensor_t sensor;
  dht.begin();
  delayMS = sensor.min_delay / 1000;
}

void loop() {
  delay(delayMS);
  sensors_event_t event;
  dht.temperature().getEvent(&event);
  if (isnan(event.temperature)) {
    Serial.println(F("Error reading temperature!"));
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(F("Temperature: "));
    Serial.print(event.temperature);
    Serial.println(F("°C"));
  }
  dht.humidity().getEvent(&event);
  if (isnan(event.relative_humidity)) {
    Serial.println(F("Error reading humidity!"));
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(F("Humidity: "));
    Serial.print(event.relative_humidity);
    Serial.println(F("%"));
  }
}
```

board - Arduino Uno (R3)

Comment: Welcome to Arduino:SE.  Without seeing your code and hardware setup, we have no way to answer your question.

Comment: @sempaiscuba thanks for correcting me. I have edited it now, let me know if there are some further corrections.

Comment: I would print something unique in `setup()` that makes it evident in the output listing that it is only running once.

Comment: What is the actual value of `delayMS`? The calculation looks fishy, since `sensor` is not initialized. The value should be around 2500ms.

Comment: @PMF It says its 2000ms

Comment: Do you have ModemManager installed on your system? Could you check that nobody else is messing with the serial port? Like this: `sudo fuser -v /dev/ttyACM0`.

Comment: Evidently DHT11 sensors need at least 2 seconds to make a new reading.  Consider waiting slightly more than 2 seconds in your loop. Personally I couldn't get a DHTxx to work reliably and switched to, I believe, an si7021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, you are trying to read the sensor at a rate that is too fast.

Try changing this line:

```
delayMS = sensor.min_delay / 1000;
```

to:

```
delayMS = sensor.min_delay = 1000;
```

or:

```
delayMS = sensor.min_delay = 3000;
```

This will read the sensor at a slower rate and should give you clean output.